# Webpack not transpiling Typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to build up a simple website, so I decided learn/use webpack to pack everything for me. I decided to use TypeScript and SASS, as I work with both daily.

I followed step by step from the https://webpack.js.org. I tried `awesome-typescript-loader` and `ts-loader` but both are not working when I try to use ES6/TypeScript features in my code, like defining types or even using classes.

When trying to transpile my `main.ts` I got this:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/main.ts
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:17)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import { Slider } from './components/slider/slider.component';
|
| const contactForm: ContactForm = new ContactForm('#contact-form');
|
| const slider: Slider = new Slider('#slider-container', '.slide');
```

My `main.ts`

```
import { ContactForm } from './components/contact-form/contact-form.component';
import { Slider } from './components/slider/slider.component';

const contactForm: ContactForm = new ContactForm('#contact-form');

const slider = new Slider('#slider-container', '.slide');
```

My `slider.component.ts`

```
export class Slider {

  private container: HTMLElement;
  private slides: HTMLElement[];

  constructor(containerSelector: string, slidesSelector: string) {
    this.container = document.querySelector(containerSelector);
    this.slides = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(slidesSelector));

    const containerWidth: number = this.slides
                                      .map(slide => slide.offsetWidth)
                                      .reduce((sum, offsetWidth) => sum + offsetWidth, 0);

    this.container.style.width = `${containerWidth}px`;
  }
}
```

If I remove the types then it transpiles the `main.ts` and I get this errors:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/components/contact-form/contact-form.component.ts
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| export class ContactForm {
|
|   private form: any;
|
|   constructor(formSelector: string) {
 @ ./src/app/main.ts 1:0-79

ERROR in ./src/app/components/slider/slider.component.ts
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| export class Slider {
|
|   private container: HTMLElement;
|   private slides: HTMLElement[];
|
 @ ./src/app/main.ts 2:0-62
```

My `webpack.common.js`

```
const path = require("path");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require("fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  devtool: "source-map",
  entry: {
    scripts: "./src/app/main.ts",
    styles: "./src/app/styles.scss",
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".scss"],
    symlinks: false,
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: "/\.tsx?$/",
        use: {
          loader: "ts-loader",
          options: {
            configFile: "./tsconfig.json",
            happyPackMode: true,
            transpileOnly: true,
          },
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader",
            options: {
              insertAt: "top",
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: { sourceMap: true },
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: { sourceMap: true },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [ "file-loader" ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [ "file-loader" ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(["dist"]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "src/app/index.html",
    }),
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
      checkSyntaticErrors: true,
    }),
  ],
};
```

My `webpack.dev.js`:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const common = require("./webpack.common.js");

module.exports = merge(common, {
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./dist",
    clientLogLevel: "none",
    port: 3000,
    hot: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
});
```

My `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "declaration": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

My `package.json`

```
 ...
 "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.17",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^0.2.9",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "ts-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.5",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^8.0.54"
  }
```

Comment: have you had a look at this https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html ? You might be missing `"jsx": "react"` in the `"compilerOptions"` of your `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the following line:

```
    test: "/\.tsx?$/",
```

to remove the quotes, making it a regex:

```
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
```